# find memory limit programmatically in cgi python script?

Tags: python, memory, cgi

Working with large in memory objects and was wondering if there's a way to check how much memory a python CGI process is allocated from within a script?

Answer (score 1):

If you're on a UNIX machine, you can try the information from the documentation on resource. Not sure exactly what you want but resource.RLIMIT_STACK or resource.RLIMIT_DATA (heap) could be what you're looking for.

http://docs.python.org/2/library/resource.html

Answer (score 0):

It is very unlikely there is a standard way to do this. If the value is not in the environment, you can not find it programmatically. How is the script run (server, module...)?